# lsyncd -- one way synchronisation but for the whole folder

Tags: rsync, lsyncd

I have two folders `~/A` and `~/B`. With some content.

I write an `lsyncd` configuration file `~/.config/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf`:

```
# NOTE: Use only absolute path names
# NOTE: check "man rsync" for parameters inside "rsync{}".

# Global settings
settings {
    logfile = "/home/ziga/.config/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/home/ziga/.config/lsyncd/lsyncd-status.log",
    statusInterval = 5
}

# Synchronisation A ⟶ B
sync {
    default.rsync,
    source = "/home/ziga/A",
    target = "/home/ziga/B",
    delete = true,
    rsync = {
        binary = "/usr/bin/rsync",
        executability = true,
        existing = false,
    }
}
```

And I start `lsyncd` like this:

```
lsyncd -nodaemon ~/.config/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf
```

> **Note:** Parameter `-nodemon` is there only to give me more information
> in the terminal where I run the above command.

Immediately after the command is executed, synchronisation takes place and content of folder `~/A` is transfered to the folder `~/B`. This is okay.

According to my configuration file I would expect that if I delete a file in `~/B`, it will not be deleted from `~/A` which is also the case! And this is a wanted behaviour - I want to prevent accidental deletion of content in folder `~/A`.

But at this point I would also expect that `lsyncd` will detect that folder `~/B` is missing a just deleted file and will sync the folders again by copying the missing file from `~/A` to `~/B` like it does immediately when it is started! **But this does not happen.**

How can this be done?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time that an OP is not presenting his whole configuration to make the problem "easier" to understand ;-) So please allow me to ask whether this is *really* your *whole* configuration. Notably, do you use any layer 1, layer 2 or layer 3 configuration which you don't show here?

Comment: Maybe this link helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/921983/lsyncd-taking-time-to-sync-files

Comment: @Binarus This is a whole configuration. I am using only *"Layer 4"* according to the official manual: https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/manual/config/layer4/

Comment: @K-att- Link that you posted does not deal with this problem. It deals with delays.

Comment: @71GA OK, thanks. I was somehow mistrustful because in your config there is a comma after `existing = false`, which is unusual; I have no clue whether this is valid syntax at all.

Comment: I removed comma and behaviour rremains the same. I also removed all the comments just in case and it does not help.

Comment: Apart from my answer below: What versions are your `rsync` and `lsyncd` at?

Comment: Yes, the link talking about the delays. I thought your problem solve when you wait a while. Sorry, may it was not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have two questions which probably should be treated separately. Let's first have a look to the second one, because it is easier to answer:

> But at this point I would also expect that lsyncd will detect that folder ~/B is missing a just deleted file and will sync the folders again by copying the missing file from ~/A to ~/B like it does immediately when it is started!

With your configuration, you can't expect immediate reaction when a file is deleted at the *target*. `lsyncd` uses `inotify` to watch for changes in the *source* file tree. Actually, after the initial synchronization which happens upon starting, it doesn't know what happens at the *target*. Instead, from time to time (see below), it calls `rsync` to reflect the changes in the *source* tree to the *target*.

Theoretically, `lsyncd` could monitor the target via `inotify` as well *as long as the target is local*. But usually this is not the case. Let's suppose the target is on a remote host (in contrast to your example). How could `lsyncd` be notified then about a file in the *remote target* being deleted?

This is not a problem, though: The next time `lsyncd` starts a new synchronization (by executing `rsync`), the file will be created again. That is, while there is no *immediate* reaction to a file being deleted on the target, that file will be copied again in the next `rsync` run. The next `rsync` run happens after a certain number of changes in the *source* tree (see below) or upon startup.

Please note that you can configure how often `lsyncd` runs the synchronization via `rsync`. As far as I have understood, there is a default timeout, but additionally, if `lsyncd` notices 1000 (default value) changes in the *source* tree (via `inotify`), then (regardless of the timeout) it runs `rsync` to synchronize all of them at once. Of course, this is by far better than running `rsync` after every single change.

So, coming to your final question ("How can this be done"), **it can't be done at all**, or requires some programming. In every case, you would have to run a daemon which watches for file system changes on the *target* and then on its own executes `rsync` to sync the files from the *source* to the *target*, or which in case of such changes notifies another daemon at the *source* which in turn runs `rsync`.

But then you wouldn't need `lsyncd` any more, because with that knowledge you probably would build your own two-way synchronization system.

Now let's get to your first problem:

> According to my configuration file I would expect that if I delete a file in ~/B, it will not be deleted from ~/A which is also the case!

I am not able to tell immediately what is going wrong here; it really shouldn't happen given your configuration. However, I have a suggestion regarding further analysis:

When starting `lsyncd`, add the parameter `-log Exec`. Your command line then would read:

```
lsyncd -log Exec -nodaemon ~/.config/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf
```

This will log the command lines of all processes `lsyncd` spawns (in your case, to the terminal). I am very confident that we can identify the problem when you post those command lines (preferably, as an update in your original question); they should show how `rsync` is executed, including the command line parameters. Perhaps I can help with analysis, but to be honest, I am not that deep in `rsync`.

Comment: This *"you can configure how often lsyncd runs the synchronization via rsync. As far as I have understood, by default lsyncd waits until it has noticed 1000 changes in the source tree (via inotify), then runs rsync to synchronize all of them at once."* was eyes opening. My setup was correct all the time, but i always only deleted a couplle of files and this is not nearly enough to trigger the `rsync` symchronisation. Therefore I thought this does not work. But I was wrong. I did leave `lsyncd` on for a longer period and everything was synced at the end! So... Problem solved!

Comment: Thanks for the bounty :-). As a final hint, you can configure the number of changes that make `lsyncd` trigger an `rsync` run; please have a look into the `maxDelays` parameter. You also can alter the *timeout* after which `lsyncd` triggers an `rsync` run; please look into the `delay` parameter. In fact, `lsyncd` takes action after whichever comes first (timeout, or number of changes).